# How to get a city's Lat,Alt on google maps API having only the name of the city

Tags: google-maps, javascript

I'm trying to locate a city latitude and longitude only by having it's name.

I'm trying to use only the Gmaps API and avoiding the use of the webservice that google offers for geolocation.

Comment: Literally having only the city? That will be problematic as a given city name could represent numerous different locations. There is no uniqueness of city names.

Answer (score 0):

after doing a search you can get coordinates trough `place.Point.coordinates`

example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps API Sample</title>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAA1XbMiDxx_BTCY2_FkPh06RRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQEerTAUcfkyrr6OwBovxn7TDAH5Q"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var map;
        var geocoder;

        function initialize() {
         map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
         map.setCenter(new GLatLng(34, 0), 1);
         geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        }

        // addAddressToMap() is called when the geocoder returns an
        // answer.  It adds a marker to the map with an open info window
        // showing the nicely formatted version of the address and the country code.
        function addAddressToMap(response) {
         map.clearOverlays();
         if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
           alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address");
         } else {
           place = response.Placemark[0];
           point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],
                               place.Point.coordinates[0]);
           marker = new GMarker(point);
           map.addOverlay(marker);
  -->      // here you get the coordinates of the founded point
           marker.openInfoWindowHtml('<b>Coordinates:</b> ' + place.Point.coordinates);
         }
        }

        // showLocation() is called when you click on the Search button
        // in the form.  It geocodes the address entered into the form
        // and adds a marker to the map at that location.
        function showLocation() {
         var address = document.forms[0].q.value;
         geocoder.getLocations(address, addAddressToMap);
        }

        // findLocation() is used to enter the sample addresses into the form.
        function findLocation(address) {
         document.forms[0].q.value = address;
         showLocation();
        }

        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()" style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
        <!-- Creates a simple input box where you can enter an address
             and a Search button that submits the form. //-->
        <form action="#" onsubmit="showLocation(); return false;">
          <p>
            <b>Search cities:</b>
            <input type="text" name="q" value="" class="address_input" size="40" />
            <input type="submit" name="find" value="Search" />

          </p>
        </form>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
      </body>
    </html>​
```